# KDevelop - Show prototype while entering

Tags: c, ide, kdevelop

I've just started with KDevelop and I'm trying write a call to a C function with a lot of parameters. When I enter the name of a function KDevelop's syntax suggestion will show the function's prototype but when I start typing it will hide the suggestion. I would like to see the fields I am entering, is it possible to keep the prototype visible when typing?